# How to extract data by matching a variable with the tag value in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
!--This is the first table from where i get 4 id's (abc1---abc4) which i need to match with the table below and get the required data--!
<table width="100%" border="0" class=""BigClass">
<tbody>..</tbody>
</table>

!--This is the second table --!
<table width="100%" border="0" class=""BigClass">
<tbody>
<tr align="left">
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
<strong>   1.              
             First Topic
</strong>
<a name="abc1" id="abc1"></a>
</td>
</tr>
!--This is the place where the first speaker and his/her text comes---!
<tr align="left">
<td style="text-align:justify;line-height:2;padding-right:10px;" colspan="2">
<strong> "   First Speaker    "    </strong>
<br>
"    Some Text   "
</td>
</tr>

!--This is where the second speaker comes in---!
<tr align="left">
<td style="text-align:justify;line-height:2;padding-right:10px;" colspan="2">
<strong>  "  Second Speaker    "   </strong>
<br>
     "   Some Text   "    
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><br></td></tr>

!--Then here comes the row with another id--!
<tr align="left">
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
<strong>   2.              
             Second Topic
</strong>
<a name="abc2" id="abc2"></a>
</td>
</tr>
!--Just like before, this will also have set of speakers who have some text--!
```

I have two tables with the same class name which is BigClass. From the first table i extracted 4 ids which are abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4.
Now i want to check that if these ids is present in this second table(which it is)
after it matches with the ids in the second table, i want to extract the speakers and the text of those speakers.
You can see the code structure for the second table rom which i want to extract the data.

Comment: Please provide the whole HTML file and properly format it.

Comment: Thanks@Nitin for a response. The html looks like
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" class=""BigClass">
<tbody>
<strong> 1.First Topic </strong>
<a name="abc1" id="abc1"></a>
<strong> "   First Speaker    "    </strong>
<br>"Some Text   "
<strong>  "  Second Speaker    "   </strong>
<br>"   Some Text   "    
!--Then here comes the row with another id--!
<strong>   2.Second Topic
</strong>
<a name="abc2" id="abc2"></a>
!--Just like before, this will also have set of speakers who have some text--!
My question is how do i fetch  only the speaker and their text for Different Topics using that id

Comment: The full code is in the original post above

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to extract speaker and text information is to extract all ids in a list and all speaker info in another list. Then just cross-reference the ids needed and get the corresponding speaker info.

I create a dictionary here with key as ids and value as speaker info. I found the speaker info by the condition that the td field has a style attribute defined in all fields containing speaker info.

For extracting info from HTML, I am using the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import izip

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('table.html'))
idList = []
speakerList = []
idsRequired = ['abc1','abc2']
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'id' in a.attrs.keys():
        idList.append(a.attrs['id'])

for i in soup.findAll('td'):
    if 'style' in i.attrs.keys():
        speakerList.append(i.text)

for key,value in izip(idList,speakerList):
    if key in idsRequired:
        print value
```

This gives me the output as:

```
"     First speaker   "
"   Some text     "


"     Second speaker   "
"   Some text     "
```

Comment: @Nitin-I tried the code you have mentioned below. But it shows KeyError: 'id' first time. I am trying to see what the problem is.Can you lease tell me why am i facing this error?. But thanks for the code, gives me a better logic.

Comment: @Nitin-@Nitin-Yes this one is correct but not exactly what i wanted. My idea was to print those two speakers only for id abc1 and not abc2. With id as abc it will print the speakers which is below it before it reaches abc3 and so on. Hope you understand my question more.

Comment: @user2657822 the KeyError is shown when you don't have the 'id' attribute in your <a> tags. This code will work if you have ids corresponding to every <a> tag in your HTML code and a corresponding <td> tag having speaker info. I have edited the code to check if id key exists or not.

Comment: You can just vary the idsRequired list to get the ids you need. To understand how BeautifulSoup works, it might be worthwhile to go through their documentation.

Comment: @Nitin-The error is not there anymore, but i think the id verification doesnt work here. If i put idsRequired = ['abc1'], it should display firstspeaker and secondspeaker both but it does not. I am trying but couldnt work it out.